# Dose an application (executable jar) need permission to listen on a port on centos?

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot, centos

I am running a Spring Boot application that I exported from Eclipse as an executable JAR. I have tested it on local host on a Windows machine, both in Eclipse and as an executable JAR.

On my local Windows machine, I can connect to the executable JAR’s REST API using RESTClient for Firefox. The executable also successfully sends a message to a remote server when it initialises on my windows device.

I am trying to deploy the executable to a CentOS device to test it. I have allowed all traffic through the firewall by setting the default for Input to accept using IP tables (I know, a very bad idea, but the device won't be alive for more than a few mins for a demo).

The executable JAR runs on the CentOS system. It says it is listening on port 8080, it successfully sends information to another remote server when initialised; but I cannot access the REST API delivered by the Spring application.

The executable launches on the CentOS server without any complication. I can ping the centOS server, I can SSH into the server; but when I try using RESTCLient to access the machine, I am told that the URL is invalid, and when I try make a GET request using my browser I am told the connection was reset. On the console for the spring application nothing registers when I try and make a connection to the device.

Can I deploy the application to the CentoOS server in this way or does it need additional permissions to listen to a port? Please Advises!

Comment: disable selinux and try.

Comment: @Nonika I had not dissabled SELinux. I have since disabled SELinux but am still unable to connect to the application. Dose an application running on a linux system need special permission to bind to a port?

Comment: Ports below 1024 generally need permission. But i think there is no permission issue. Can you check via tcpdump if packets are coming?

Comment: @Nonika, thanks for the advice. I will check this but do not have the time to do so now. I am finishing college now but will pursue this course of inquiry in a few months. I am curious to see what was wrong. As it stands I got it working for one version of the executable on the VM but it would not work for another version of the executable on the VM, so I can only assume it is the JAR's fault but I haven’t change any of the Spring boot configuration between versions of the Jar.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a firewall activated?
So you have to open the port in the firewall settings:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent
```

Then remember to reload the firewall for changes to take effect.

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. I have no rules on the input chain in IPTables and I had default for the input chain set to accept all traffic. Would that be enough to allow traffic through to the Jar? I did not have any other firewall operating. I got this working for one version of the Jar and not for another version of the program in the meantime and forgot to reply, I apologise... I am now assuming it was something to do with the executable. I guess my main question is still, dose a program running on Linux need special permissions to bind to a port, outside of firewall rules (and SELinux)